# Google App Engine SDK 1.9.25 refused by GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sdk

I've downloaded latest Java GAE SDK 1.9.25 (1.9.25 - 2015-08-12) and when I want to compile my app and deploy it, I get strange error on console:

```
The API version in this SDK is no longer supported on the server!
 -----------
 Latest SDK:
 Release: 1.9.25
 Timestamp: Tue Jul 07 21:10:33 CEST 2015
 API versions: [1]

 -----------
 Your SDK:
 Release: 1.9.25
 Timestamp: Thu Jul 23 21:07:39 CEST 2015
 API versions: [1.0]
```

My SDK is 1.9.25 (July 23) and remote is 1.9.25 (July 5) and it's no longer supported?

What is that?

Answer (score 0):

This should only be a warning. I just downloaded the newest SDK. I saw the above then re-ran the appcfg and it went through without issue. There is an open [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12307&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) for this. I would 'Star' it to get updates.